# blocking sockets and select

Tags: python, linux, sockets, network-programming, ipc

i'm playing around with sockets, and I'm having some doubts about using blocking sockets with select.Let's assume i'm only tracking potential readers.  Am I right in thinking that select will go through the first socket in the list and if some data is available it will return and if not it will block until select's timeout expires? When will the other sockets in the read list be checked by select?

Let me illustrate with a python example for simplicity:

```
servsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
servsock.bind(("", 2500))
servsock.listen(15)
servsock.setblocking(1)

readlist = [servsock]

while 1:
    (sread, swrite, sexc) =  select.select(readlist, [], [] ); 

    for sock in sread:

        #received a connect to the server socket
        if  sock == servsock:

        (newsock, address) = servsock.accept()
            newsock.setblocking(1)
            print "I got a connection from ", address
            readlist.append(newsock)
            newsock.send("you're connected to the select server")
        else:
            recv_msg = sock.recv(5)

            if recv_msg == "":
                (host, port) = sock.getpeername()
                print "Client %s:%s closed the connection" % (host,port)
                sock.close()
                readlist.remove(sock)
            else:
                (host, port) = sock.getpeername()
                print "client %s:%s sent: %s "% (host,port,recv_msg)
```

Since they're blocking sockets, will select always block when testing to see if the socket in the list has data to read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `select()` C API returns a list of all sockets that are currently readable. Assuming python's wrapper does the same, `sread` will contain multiple elements if multiple sockets are readable.

A blocking socket will only block if there is no data present, so after a `select()` call indicated there is data, you can assume that *one* call to `recv` will not block.

Comment: so in other words, select works the same way for blocking and non-blocking sockets?

Comment: Yes, it only tells you whether data is available, not whether reads would block. That reads generally do not block if data is available, even if it means returning less data than was asked for is a property of `recv()`.

Answer (score 2):

`select()` will block until one of the sockets has data.  It doesn't check only the first one, it checks everything in your `readlist` variable.

In `for sock in sread:` it iterates through all the sockets that have data to be read.